# Why did Worker kill executor?

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark

I'm programing spark application in spark standalone cluster. When I run following code, I got below ClassNotFoundException(reference screenshot). So, I follow the worker(192.168.111.202) log.

```
package main

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

object mavenTest {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("stream test").setMaster("spark://192.168.111.201:7077")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val input = sc.textFile("file:///root/test")

    val words = input.flatMap { line => line.split(" ") }


    val counts = words.map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey { case (x, y) => x + y }

    counts.saveAsTextFile("file:///root/mapreduce")
  }
}
```

[image]

Following logs are worker's log. These logs say worker kill executor, and error occur. Why did Worker kill executor? Could you give any clue?

```
16/03/24 20:16:48 INFO Worker: Asked to launch executor app-20160324201648-0011/0 for stream test
16/03/24 20:16:48 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root
16/03/24 20:16:48 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root
16/03/24 20:16:48 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(root); users with modify permissions: Set(root)
16/03/24 20:16:48 INFO ExecutorRunner: Launch command: "/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_73/jre/bin/java" "-cp" "/opt/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.6/sbin/../conf/:/opt/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-assembly-1.5.2-hadoop2.6.0.jar:/opt/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:/opt/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar:/opt/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar:/etc/hadoop" "-Xms1024M" "-Xmx1024M" "-Dspark.driver.port=40243" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "akka.tcp://sparkDriver@192.168.111.201:40243/user/CoarseGrainedScheduler" "--executor-id" "0" "--hostname" "192.168.111.202" "--cores" "1" "--app-id" "app-20160324201648-0011" "--worker-url" "akka.tcp://sparkWorker@192.168.111.202:53363/user/Worker"
16/03/24 20:16:54 INFO Worker: Asked to kill executor app-20160324201648-0011/0
16/03/24 20:16:54 INFO ExecutorRunner: Runner thread for executor app-20160324201648-0011/0 interrupted
16/03/24 20:16:54 INFO ExecutorRunner: Killing process!
16/03/24 20:16:54 ERROR FileAppender: Error writing stream to file /opt/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.6/work/app-20160324201648-0011/0/stderr
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:170)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:283)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
        at org.apache.spark.util.logging.FileAppender.appendStreamToFile(FileAppender.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.util.logging.FileAppender$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileAppender.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.util.logging.FileAppender$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FileAppender.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.util.logging.FileAppender$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FileAppender.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1699)
        at org.apache.spark.util.logging.FileAppender$$anon$1.run(FileAppender.scala:38)
16/03/24 20:16:54 INFO Worker: Executor app-20160324201648-0011/0 finished with state KILLED exitStatus 143
16/03/24 20:16:54 INFO Worker: Cleaning up local directories for application app-20160324201648-0011
16/03/24 20:16:54 INFO ExternalShuffleBlockResolver: Application app-20160324201648-0011 removed, cleanupLocalDirs = true
```

Comment: What is the full line of your ClassNotFoundException?

Comment: It is "16/03/25 03:03:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, 192.168.111.202): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: main.mapreduce$$anonfun$2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's your spark version? This is a spark's known bug, and fixed in version 1.6.
More detail u can see [[SPARK-9844]](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/10714)

Comment: I used 1.5.2. and almost forgot about this problem. Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I found it was problem about memory, but I don't know well why this problem happen. just add following property in yarn-site.xml file. Apache hadoop say this configure decide whether virtual memory limits will be enforced for containers.

```
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled</name>
<value>false</value>
</property>
```